# Not equals comparison on cased letters

Tags: python, comparison, operator-keyword, control-flow

I have this:

```
salir = ""
while  salir != "s" or salir != "S":
       print("no has salido")
       salir = input("Digit s to exit or enter to continue)
print("saliste")
```

but the operator != doesnt work, but if I put this:

```
salir = ""
while  not (salir == "s" or salir == "S"):
       print("no has salido")
       salir = input("Digit s to exit or enter to continue")
print("saliste")
```

the code works normal, the problem is the comparison operator != because if I change that by " not == " this works. Can anybody explain the problem?

Comment: You changed more than just the operator there. `(x != y) or (x != z)` is not the same as `~(x = y or x = z)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you are evaluating always returns `True`

```
salir != "s" or salir != "S" == True  # always
```

If the user inputs 's', then `salir != "S"`

If the user inputs 'S', then `salir != "s"`

If you want to split the two cases (instead of calling the `lower()` method) you can use the loop

```
while  salir != "s" and salir != "S":
    # Do stuff
```

By DeMorgan's law this is equivalent to

```
while  not (salir == "s" or salir == "S"):
    # Do stuff
```

Comment: Oh Thanks, I dont know how I forget evaluate the complete expressions as it should be, I guide myself just to evaluate each part of them but with fogetting sense :) , Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 2):

```
while  salir != "s" or salir != "S":
```

If salir is **"s"** it's different than **"S"**, if it's **"S"**, it's different than **"s"**.
So, your condition is always true.

If we change the letters make it easier to understand.

while  salir != "a" or salir != "b":

While your variable is different than a or is different than b, it always will be different than one of the two options, so the condition is always true.

You can do a single comparison just changing the case of the variable, like:

```
while salir.lower() != "s":
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the following:

```
salir = ""
while True:
  print("no has salido")
  salir = input("Digit s to exit or enter to continue")
  if salir.lower() == "s": break
print("saliste")
```

Comment: Thanks , my fancy was dont use any method´s :).

Answer (score 0):

If you fancy regular expressions, I absolutely love the "re" module.

```
import re

def main():
    counter = 0
    taco = "q"

    while re.search(re.compile(r"s",re.IGNORECASE),taco) == None:
        print("no")
        if counter == 5:
            print("taco = s")
            taco = "S"
        else:
            pass
        counter += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which gives the output:

```
no
no
no
no
no
no
taco = s
```

While this will use more CPU cycles, it does allow for some greater flexibility with having multiple cases, or options, in a custom designed regular expression. I usually use expressions in most of my code so I don't feel as bad for wasting a few extra CPU cycles.

re.search will search the string looking for the argument where-as re.match would require a string to match your expression completely; these would return a re object. re.findall would return a list of results so one could do "while re.findall(...) == 0:" as well.

Please refer to the "re" documentation for more information:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html